# Date as Index of Graph

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I'm creating a Graph using CanvasJS.Chart with an interval set to 14 days. How to set the starting index of Xaxis in the graph to a specified date(eg:02/08/2018)?

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: ""
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "Time",
        valueFormatString: "DD MMM,YY",
        interval: 14,
        intervalType: "day",
        minimum: new Date(2018,08,02)

    }, 
...
```

Comment: what is the format of your date (e.g `x` value in the data array)?

Comment: dataPoints: [
   { x: new Date(2018,08,02), y: 0 }]

Comment: @DerekNguyen  dataPoints: [ { x: new Date(2018,08,02), y: 0 }]

Comment: hey friend, thanks for the clarification -- I plugged your code into a codepen and it seems to work as expected? perhaps you just couldn't see the `y` value because it was set to 0? https://codepen.io/d4rek/pen/EGrRRq?editors=1000

Comment: @DerekNguyen I want to set the Xaxis index label. Like 2 Sep 18, 16 Sep 18... That is in an interval of 14 days. (Not 7 Sep 18 as in the default case).

Comment: ah I see, that is odd, the default doesn't seem to be changable when the data type is day :/ hope you have better luck contacting the devs